# Wpf DataGrid: how to detect the set of visible cells?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, scroll, datagrid

I have a Wpf DataGrid the user can sort by clicking on any header, and scroll.
Some cells need to display images, but I would like to avoid to load all the images when populating the DataGrid. I'd like the images to be loaded only when they fall into view, instead.
How can I be notified when a cell comes into view, and How do I get its bounded item?

Comment: Have a look at wpf data virtualization, there a some helpfule articles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:
Listen for the DataGrid's ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event:

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="DataGrid_ScrollChanged">
```

then, use the scrollviewer properties to detect the visible rows; finally work with the DataGrid's ItemContainerGenerator to get the item associated to each row of interest.

```
    private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void DataGrid_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scroll = GetChildOfType<ScrollViewer>((DependencyObject)sender);
        int firstRow = (int)scroll.VerticalOffset;
        int lastRow = (int)scroll.VerticalOffset + (int)scroll.ViewportHeight + 1;
        DataGrid datagrid = sender as DataGrid;
        for (int i = firstRow; i < lastRow; i++)
        {
            var row = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null)
            {
                var item = row.DataContext;
                ItemViewModel viewModel = item as ItemViewModel;
                if (viewModel != null)
                {
                    viewModel.LoadImages().ContinueWith(t => { });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I hope that ItemViewModel doesn't load a bitmap of any sorts?! One would usually use a converter in xaml to load said images. If your ViewModel has a reference to ANY UI element or type, it is no longer MVVM. And Virtualisation is the way to go, this solution may work (reeks of WinForms though) but it is more of a hack rather than solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `EnableDataVirtualization="True"` to the `DataGrid`